# Html inputs become un-responsive when window is re-sized or on mobile screens

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a form in my application that works well until the window is re-sized or if you view it on mobile. For some reason the last controls; a drop down and a text-box become unresponsive.

Meaning when i click it nothing happens, when i tap the screen nothing happens, the select menu doesn't appear, the text-box doesn't get focus.  This is the weirdest thing i have seen and i dunno why this is happening.

This problem only occurs when the window is a smaller screen.
This is the html of the two controls:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group" ng-init="getSecurityQuestions()">
        <label class="control-label small-font">Security Question*</label>
        <ui-select ng-model="form.security_question" theme="bootstrap" required>
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one...">{{$select.selected.text }}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="question in security_questions">
                {{ question.text }}
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label small-font" for="security_answer">Your Answer*</label>
        <input type="text" id="security_answer" ng-model="form.security_answer" class="form-control" min="3" required />
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought it might be the ui-select directive causing it so i took it out but still the other text-box wouldn't work on a small screen.

Comment: That doesn't really matter, the classes i mean, i was trying the display on different screen sizes and adjusting them, i can take out col-md-12 and col-sm-12 still won't make a difference.  As for the css issue you mentioned i use bootstrap.

Comment: The only change i made to form-control was to give it a 'border-radius of 0 !important' to overwrite the default style.

Comment: try removing the col-xs-12 class and report back. Then try removing col-sm-12 too.

Comment: Wow your comment was really helpful, the problem appears to be with "col-xs-12" alone, "col-sm-12" and "col-md-12" work on those two elements but the minute i add "col-xs-12" they stop working. O_O

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not in your HTML code, this is from your CSS code.
Find the tag that doesn't appear when you re-sizing the window and copy a class or ID of that tag and find it on your CSS file in **@media screen** css.
Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: I'm sorry i'm confused. @_@

Comment: and look at for display:none or visibility:hidden in that class or ID

Comment: You mean in the bootstrap.css? And what tags are you referring to?

Comment: simple first get the class of that HTML part that doesn't appear and find it on your css file under @media screen tag

Comment: like if col-xs-12 class tag doesn't appear when re-sizing that search for col-xs-12 class that is under @media screen in your css